# Access the value returned by a function in a finally block

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to know if it is possible to get the return value of a function inside a finally block.

I have some code that is like this.

```
try
{
    return 1;
}
finally
{
    //Get the value 1
}
```

I know it's possible by adding a variable that can hold the returned value. But I was wondering if it was possible to get the value in any way.

Thanks

Comment: use the variable.  it will make your code clearer, easier to maintain, easier to understand.

Comment: For curiosity's sake, why would you want to do that? I'm curious to see a situation where that would be the ideal solution.

Comment: @Ian - Yep, I rarely do more than cleanup in the finally block and that's only for bad APIs.

Comment: I use the finally block to trace the information. Here it's the function called, the parameter passed and the result code. It works as a profiler to verify performance. So in the finally block, I do objectTrace.Save(ReturnValue), that's why I wanted to access the value without an extra variable.

Comment: @IanP Logging/debugging.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

Comment: the answer of Tomas Petricek is correct- simply by using wrapper

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use the variable approach and return early, you could do something like this:

```
int Method()
{
    int @return = -1;
    try
    {
        @return = -2;
        return @return;
    }
    finally
    {
        // do something with @return
    }
}
```

Comment: Or more succinctly: `return @return = -2;`

Comment: i gotta ask - what does '@' in font of variable name mean?

Comment: and for Jeffrey comment return @return = -2. WOuld that work? Which gets done first , the finally or the return

Comment: @pm100: Its escapes the keyword 'return' (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28VS.71%29.aspx).  The finally will happen after the return.

Comment: Nicely done. I havent seen the @ escaping accept in the IronPython/IronRuby source code, I didnt realize it was used regularly outside of that.

Comment: But surely the use of @ escaping of reserved words to get variable names could not be considered good practice?

Comment: @Nij: I actually never really use @ to escape keywords, but I thought it was appropriate for this example.

Answer (score 9):

```
int value = -1;

try 
{ 
    value = 1; 
} 
finally 
{ 

    // Now the value is available
} 

return value;
```

Comment: Yes, I know it's possible that way. I was just wondering if it was possible without a variable.

Comment: this way one loses the benefits of early returns :-(

Comment: Early return? Not sure what you mean @Vlad. That is effectively what the compiler will unwind the statement into anyways. Are you talking about from a visual flow standpoint?

Comment: @David: at least those who believe that early returns are a Good Thing would be unable to use their favourite techniques in this case.

Comment: @Vlad: It is still possible to return early. (see my answer)

Comment: @GrayWizardx: I am talking about the code like that:
`try { foreach (element in list) if (element is good) return element; /* other code */ } finally { ... };`.
Without early returns you would need to write it as
`try { foreach (element in list) if (element is good) { value = element; flag = true; break; } if (!flag) { /* other code with assignment to value */ } } finally { ... }; return value;`

Comment: @Vlad, I understood your statement in general (and I would suggest @Zach's code below) but not in this example. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7):

As others already mentioned, you have to use a variable in this case. However, you can wrap this behavioral pattern into a reusable method using C# 3.0 lambda functions:

```
static T TryFinally<T>(Func<T> body, Action<T> finallyHandler) { 
  T result = default(T);
  try {
    result = body();
  } finally {
    finallyHandler(result);
  }
  return result;
}
```

The `TryFinally` method allows you to write what you originally needed without repeating the pattern:

```
TryFinally(() => { 
    // body of the method
    return 1; 
  }, result => {
    // do whatever you need with 'result' here
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

VB.Net allows you to do this:

```
Public Function GetValue() As Integer
    Try
        GetValue = 2
    Catch
        'Something happens
    Finally
        'Do something with GetValue
    End Try
End Function
```

Which tells you a little bit about what the JIT compiler is going to do.

Comment: That seems a little dangerous. Wouldn't checking the GetValue in the finally block initiate a recursive call?

Comment: I haven't used VB.Net very much, but I think the parenthesis are required to do a recursive function call, so this should be safe.

Comment: This isn't recursive.  GetValue (the function name) is an available variable in vb.net. Notice there's not Return statement. When the program reaches the end of the function, the GetValue is returned (in this example, 2).

Answer (score 0):

I think the actual question is - can I systematically trace the exit (and entry?) of various functions - presumably for tracing / troubleshooting etc. How about aspect.net. This lets you insert code dynamically into things

Comment: Well it's not really the question. I was looking for that part only to not have to create a function and set it before returning the value. The tracing is only a small part of the project to see the time that each functions takes (It's a webservice, so we want to make sure the performance are still there).