# Javascript and jQuery: accessing class member variables from event callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a Javascript SDK to interact with a web service. I am using jQuery to do my AJAX calls.

When an AJAX call fails, I have registered an event handler for the ajaxError that gets called at the top of my .js file. My problem, and I don't understand why, is that when it gets called I have no way of accessing class member variables for my Akamanda.Client.

I tried adding another method for Akamanda.Client as .prototype.logError, which got called by the jQuery Ajax handler, but even then a test for (this.logging) failed as well.

How can I access class member variables from jQuery callbacks? What am I failing to understand here? Akamanda.Client.logging is undefined from the ajaxError callback.

My code for the SDK:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    // more robust error handling for different conditions
    if (Akamanda.Client.logging) {
        console.log('FAILED: ' + settings.type + ' ' + settings.url + ' => ' + exception);
    }
});

Akamanda.Client = function(options) {

    this.URL = options.URL || 'http://m-test.akamanda.com';
    this.baseURL = this.URL + '/api/' + Akamanda.API_VERSION;
    this.feedsURI = '/websyndication/feed/';

    // who is the client? (iphone/android/web)
    this.clientName = options.clientName;

    // For development: Logging and buildcurl IS ON, for production: OFF
    //this.logging = options.logging || true;
    this.logging = true;

    // called when a user is not authorised (Disabled)
    // this.logoutCallback = options.logoutCallback || null;
}

Akamanda.Client.prototype.getFeeds = function(callback){
    var feeds = [];
    $.getJSON(this.baseURL + this.feedsURI, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, feed) {
            feeds[index] = {
                name: feed.name,
                title: feed.title,
                link: feed.link
            };

        })
        callback(feeds);
    });//.error(function(err) { (disabled at the moment in favour of ajaxError event)
       //     console.log('Error: ' + err.error);
       // });    
}
```

My code for the client (in another JS source file):

```
var options = { logging: true };
myAPI = new Akamanda.Client(options);
var feeds = [];
var articles = [];

function getFeeds()
{
    myAPI.getFeeds(function(AkamandaFeeds) {
        feeds = AkamandaFeeds;
        showFeeds();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see from the code you posted, you are never instantiating an object of type Akamanda.Client.

```
var Client = new Akamanda.Client();
```

or

```
var Akamanda.Client = {};

Akamanda.Client.logging = ....
```

JSBin Example: http://jsbin.com/ajidig/1/edit

Ok, here a little example(real code but very simplified):

```
//we wrap our code in a self invoking function so that we don't pollute the global    namespace, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715805/self-invoking-functions-javascript for further details
(function(){
     //create your object that holds all your function, that are different ways to do this
     var Akamanda = {};

     //a private function 
     function ErrorHandler(clientObj) {
          this.clientObj = clientObj;
          //do whatever with clientObj
          this.log = function(){..}
     } 
      //private constructor for clientobj
     function Client(options){
         ..
     }



     Akamanda.Client = function(){

       var newClient = new Client({..});
       //setup
       Akamanda.ErrorLogging = new ErrorHandler(newClient);
       return newClient;
     }

     //bind our service to the window object to make it accesible

     window.Akamanda = Akamanda;
})()


//client

var myAPI = Akamanda.Client();
Akamanda.ErrorLogging.log();
```

I hope this basic examples helps. If you need to know more about Javascript Patterns, I can recommend this book http://jsninja.com/ by John Resig, the creator of jQuery.
Depending on what you want to do, there's also a lot of frameworks like http://backbonejs.org/ that help with this kind of stuff.

Comment: I have updated my original question to include the consumer's source as well.

Comment: Basically the same problem. if (Akamanda.Client.logging) is a static call. If I understand your example correctly, you want if(myAPI.logging) in the ajaxerror callback.

Comment: But how would I know what a consumer (i.e. who ever utilises this SDK to access the web services) chooses to call their instantiated API object?

Comment: Well that is an entirely different problem. Instead of a constructor you could provide a factory method that returns a client service. This method also registers the new client service with some kind of debugging/ error handling entity that chooses which client obj is being used in the callback. But as I said, this is more a design question and has not much to do with your original question.

Comment: I would consider that a valid answer since the answer to my question is "impossible in this context."

Comment: It's not clear and I would love for an example of how that would be done! Thank you so much, you can use as much pseudo-code as necessary. If the concepts are clear I'll be able to work with it. Thank you!

Comment: Added an example + JSBin link, hope this helps. If not I would read the suggested book or google for Javascript OOP.

Comment: Thank you rawphl for your assistance. You're a champ!